# Is it possible to restrict all admin pages except theme customisation and storefront using plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I want to restrict all admin pages except theme customise. I am `wp_set_auth_cookie()` for auto login. I don't need any other admin pages.

I write code in my plugin

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_theme_customization' );

function my_theme_customization()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow !== 'customize.php' && is_admin()) {
        header('Location:' . site_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I am not able publish with what I changed. Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.